# Css hover button effect

Tags: html, button, css

look at this fiddle [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M2f9F/1/)
When i hover(`:hover`) `background` changes but when clicked (`:active`) `box-shadow` is not changed dont know why ? This does not happen if another button does not change `background` on hover !

in this fiddle i want somehthing like combination of `button 1` and `button 2`

```
.white-button {
    background: #FFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ccc;
    font-family: MV boli,Tahoma;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.positive:enabled:hover {
    background: #99CD30;
    box-shadow: inset 2px -7px 11px rgba(80, 92, 51, 0.17)!important;
}
button:active {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.gray-button{
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px 10px;  
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom-color: #888;
}
```

**For those who cant under stand!**

As you see there are 3 buttons on fiddle with name `like` lets say then button `A,B and C` respectively.

- Now when i hover `A` i get a ***green background with an inset
  box-shadow*** .
- When i hover `B` i get a ***green background with no inset shadow***
- When i hover `C` i get ***nothing***
- When i click `A` it ***remains same***
- when i click `B` an ***inset shadow*** is created
- when i click `C` an an ***inset shadow*** is created

Now the button i want is `D` i want

- when i hover `D` i get a  i get a ***green background with an inset

  box-shadow*** .
- when i click `D` an another ***inset shadow*** is created replacing previous one.

  ***but that does not happen dont know why ?***

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - could you clarify what your expected result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is how you want it..

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/M2f9F/3/

I just played with properties that are `!important`

```
.white-button {
background: #FFF;
font-weight: normal;
color: #3b3b3b;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ccc;
font-family: MV boli,Tahoma;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
font-size: 15px;
}

.positive4:hover {
background: #99CD30;
box-shadow: inset 2px -7px 11px rgba(80, 92, 51, 0.17);
}

.positive4:active {
border-bottom-color: #999;
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) !important;    
}
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: can u explain what u did ?

Comment: Sure thing, You put !important for box-shadow of hover property, it was overriding the box-shadow for active element. I just removed it and added it to :active of same.. :-) I hope you got my point.

Comment: !important is very important :-) it overrides all the other similar properties

Comment: `!important` means ***this css property is not important or very important?*** coz *hover* is a `NOT important` and *active* is `IMPORTANT` @rahulPatil

Comment: but if so why its called `!important` ?

Comment: Just a notation mate. read more about it here : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/